# How to read a JSON file using cl-json (common lisp library) and convert the content to a string?

Tags: json, string, parsing, common-lisp

I am using Common Lisp, SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

In SLIME's REPL, I have a variable holding the file location:

```lisp
CL-USER> json-file
#P"/home/pedro/lisp/json-example.json"
```

The content of the file is:

```json
{"keyOne": "valueOne"}
```

I would like to read the data inside the file and return a string:

```lisp
"{"keyOne": "valueOne"}"
```

How can I do it? Is it possible to do it with `cl-json` famous [library](https://github.com/hankhero/cl-json)?

The documentation was terse/hard. It is not good on providing examples. I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I read from the [documentation](https://cl-json.common-lisp.dev/cl-json.html), the API is built around streams. The function `json:decode-json` is taking a stream in parameter and return [an association list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm) which is very convenient to use.

To extract a value from the key, you can use the function `(assoc :key-1 assoc-list)`. It will return a `cons` with `(key . value)`. To get the value, you need to use the `cdr` function.

```
(defparameter json-string "{\"key-1\": \"value-1\"}")

(with-input-from-string (json-stream json-string)
  (let ((lisp-data (json:decode-json json-stream)))
    (cdr (assoc :key-1 lisp-data))))
```

Obviously, if you have the data in a file you could directly use the stream:

```
(with-open-file (json-stream "myfile.json" :direction :input)
  (let ((lisp-data (json:decode-json json-stream)))
    (cdr (assoc :key-1 lisp-data))))
```

---

Edit due to the comment of OP

The content of the file is:

> {"keyOne": "valueOne"}
> I would like to read the data inside the file and return a string:
> "{"keyOne": "valueOne"}"

This question seems completely unrelated to the JSON library, but anyhow, if one need to open a file and put its content into a string, he can use a function from `uiop`.

```
* (uiop:read-file-string "test.txt")
"{\"keyOne\": \"valueOne\"}"
```

`uiop` is a library shipped with `ASDF`, so it's probably available to most Common Lisp's distributions. It's a kind of de-facto standard library and have a lot of interesting functions.

I have done the test on my computer, it's seems to work. I can certify that no data was harmed during that test.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, your approach changes the data. Maybe my explanation created a bad bias because it also changed the content. I will refactor the question;

Comment: No my approach does not change the data. The data seems to be a file on your hard-drive, the file remains unchanged. I will try to edit my post to add one answer to a question from the original post.

Comment: Ok. It outputs a data with a different **notation** from the original data. This is what I meant by changing it. Thanks for the help;