# How to convert a string representing JSON data to a string on the curl notation in Common Lisp?

Tags: json, string, parsing, common-lisp

I am using Steel Bank Common Lisp (SBCL), Emacs, and Slime.

After executing a function, I have:

```lisp
CL-USER> (my-function my-data)

"{\"key-1\": \"value-1\"}"
```

I would like to convert the string `"{\"key-1\": \"value-1\"}"` to a REST request notation on curl, so a string as: `key-1&value-1`

Examplifying the application, this is going to be the  `data` on curl:

```bash
curl --request POST --data "userId=key-1&value-1" https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
(ql:quickload :yason)

(defun json-string-to-rest-request (json-string)
  (destructuring-bind (a b) (alexandria:hash-table-plist (yason:parse json-string))
    (format nil "~a&~a" a b)))
```

You can apply it by:

```
(defparameter *json-string* "{\"key-1\": \"value-1\"}")
(defparameter *json-string-1* "{\"KeY-1\": \"value-1\"}")

(json-string-to-rest-request *json-string*)
;; => "key-1&value-1"
(json-string-to-rest-request *json-string-1*)
;; => "KeY-1&value-1"
```

Before this, I tried:

```
(ql:quickload :cl-json)

(defun json-string-to-rest (json-string)
  (with-input-from-string (s json-string)
    (destructuring-bind ((a . b)) (cl-json:decode-json s)
      (format nil "~a&~a" (string-downcase a) b))))

(json-string-to-rest *json-string*)
;; => "key-1&value-1"
```

However, the downside is that `cl-json:decode-json` transforms the json string first to `((:KEY-1 . "value-1"))` - so case sensistivity gets lost in the json key string when using `cl-json`.

The package `yason` reads-in the keys as strings and therefore preserves case-sensitivity in the key string.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I saw the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412294/how-to-read-a-json-file-using-cl-json-common-lisp-library-and-convert-the-cont  
`cl-json` changes things.